# Custom Sql Select queries within netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-server, netbeans

i am working on a assignment in school where i am using mysql workbench and netbeans.
i have to create a database for a zoo. insert,update,delete records using text fields in the gui on netbeans. 
One of the tasks i have to do is to construct a custom sql select query using the gui. i.e (Select all animals in the zoo that are from Africa) another one might be : select animals that arrived into the zoo in 2011. i have 5 tables: amphibian,bird,invertebrate,mammal,reptile. 
i asking for some one to do everything , i am just asking for some tips or ideas on the best way to it. 
i was thinking that if used multiple combo boxes and got the selected item from each of them and them merged the items into a textfield and make a sql select statement from that textfield.

any help would be greatly appreciated , thank you

Comment: I would recommend you start with a better database design. One table per animal type is going to be painful in the long run. Just make an animal table, include a primarykey, name, countryOfOriginID, typeID. Then create another table of countryOfOrigins and a 3rd table for the types. Now you can write select queries to get types of animals, origins, and sets of animals. Comboboxes are good, but no idea what you mean `merged the items into a textfield and make a sql select statement from that textfield` ~ none the less: the combo-boxes will drive the values of the sql statement.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!. I don't think i would be able to change the database design because i don't think i have enough time. the project is due in a week. so i don't think i would have enough time to re design the whole thing and normalise it and get it working netbeans again. when i said "merged the items into a textfield". i meant get values from combo boxes and set them to a string within a string variable, then set the value of the string variable to a text field. and execute the statement from the text in the text field.

Comment: I'm not a Java person, but I don't think you would want to put the SQL statement in a text box for your users to see. Just execute the SQL command once it is in the string variable.  If you can't change your database design, then you will need to know how to use the `UNION` command to solve `Select all animals from Africa`

Comment: ya cool ! ill check the union command out!